# What does Timestamping of GPIO pin means and how to achieve it?

Tags: embedded, gpio, synchronization

I did my bachelor's in CS and I am pretty new to electronics and with embedded system as my specialization, I am not able to grab some of the concepts. I have made a program which toggles an led on and off using the gpio pins for the module LPC1769. This works fine.

However, now I am trying to understand the concept of timestamping of GPIO pins, so that I can transmit data from one mcu to other.

Can any one help me with the intuition for this ?

PS: Please pardon me for the bad tags.

Comment: another term would be bit banging.  you want to create a waveform, a pulse train, so you have to use some sort of time measurement (look for timer in your mcu documentation) and change the gpio pin state (high or low) use the timer to wait some period of time, change the state, repeat.  the other side you watch for the gpio input to change, use the timer to measure the time between one state change and another.  design a protocol (bit bang a uart type serial stream for example, or with multiple pins spi)

Comment: Sid, could you give us more context?  Could you post a paragraph where "GPIO" and "timestamping" have appeared together?  Using GPIO to transmit data (usually serially) is usually called "[bit banging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging)";  I've never hear "timestamping" used to described that.

Comment: @NickAlexeev http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html                      this is the link where I saw that term, I am trying to visualize how can I acheive sync when transmitting data from one mcu to other mcu using gpio pins. Plus, I am not sure why my professor said that we would need to maintain the same bit rate on tx and rx so as to transmit data.

Comment: The timestamping tells you when a change actually occured. This is useful because there is a short, variable delay before the event actually is processed by a userspace program. For transmission, your life will be much easier if you use SPI.

Comment: Data transmission happens either synchronously/Async with serial/parrallel data interface. I don't know what you mean by timestamping for data transfer

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion here. The link that you gave is not very clear what they mean.

Do you know what a [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) is ? It is a stamp that can be set to a certain date, sometimes added with the time. With some ink, the timestamp can be set on important documents. It was used quite often 30 years ago.
Some timestamps had a clock inside to keep it automatically at the right time.

The general meaning in program code is to remember the date and time for a certain event. For example a pin changed from low to high at october 6, 2017 at 22 hours, 0 minutes, 10 seconds, 123 milliseconds. 
The timestamp does not have to be the real date. The value of a (hardware) timer can be used as well.

With Arduino code, the millis function can be used for a timestamp.

When dealing with complex code, for example a full linux operating system, it can be useful to know the time that a certain event happened. It is important to know how accurate the timestamp is. Perhaps the "5 µs" in the link that you gave is the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret "timestamping of GPIO pins" as noting down the status of GPIO pin with respect to time. This can be either saving it in some memory or spit-out on debug port. 
Another way to correlate GPIO pin with time is to route a stable clock to another GPIO, so an external entity can relate the GPIO status with the clock.